# AWSのインスタンスのスケールアップ方法

Tags: aws

AWSのEC２ですでに作ってある、インスタンスをスケールアップさせることはできますか？
CPUやメモリ、インスタンスの変更といった画面が見つからないのですが。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

仮想化タイプ hvmとなっていますが、こちらのインスタンスは変更不可能でしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 参考 [インスタンスタイプを変更する](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html)

Answer (score 0):

インスタンスタイプ(t2.micro)を変更することにより、メモリサイズ、CPU数を変更することができます。
AWSのマネジメントコンソールにてインスタンスを選択し、コンテキストメニューの「インスタンスの設定」→「インスタンスタイプの変更」でインスタンスタイプを変更することができます。
インスタンスタイプを変更すると料金が変わってきますので注意が必要です。